# I'm getting an error saying my deeplinks are not working because the ACTION_VIEW attribute failed in GooglePlay

Tags: android, deep-linking, google-play-console, intentfilter, actionview

I'm getting an error saying my deeplinks ‭http://www.website.com/
and ‭https://www.website.com/  are not working because the ACTION_VIEW attribute failed. It says I need to add ACTION_VIEW intent to the intent filter in my manifest. I do have this implemented so I'm confused on why this is an error.

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="www.website.com" />
                <data android:pathPrefix="/app" />
            </intent-filter>
```

I haven't tried anything as of now.